# How to extend / edit Netbeans' auto-generated REST services?

Tags: java, json, rest, netbeans

I am new to the automatic generation of REST services code from a Database in Netbeans 8.

> Disclaimer: after a discussion (in the comments), I realized that I
>   should warn to avoid this question if you are not familiar with the
>   automatic generation of REST service from DB in Netbeans
>   (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html). That's because you
>   need to know what is going on and where to put your hands in order to
>   edit them. I don't provide any non-working code here, rather I want to know what should I do in order to edit such services. I provide an example of what I would like to obtain.

I did the automatic code generation of REST services from DB and obtained entity classes and service "*facade*" classes. What I need to do now is to extend / edit those services and I don't know where to put my hands.

For instance, consider the following scenario. I have a student and he/she passed many exams. From the DB perspective, student-exam is a 1 to many relationship. 
When I test the rest API and perform a GET by ID of a student, the resulting JSON does not contain a collection of exams associated with that student, as expected.
Where and how should I change the auto-generated service code in order to obtain the exams collection within the student's json?

In other words, assuming I perform a GET to 
`../student/12`, what I want to obtain is:

```
{ 
  "id":12, "name":"Marco", "age":26, "exams": [
   { "id":1, "exam_name":"Computer Networks" },
   { "id":15, "exam_name":"Algorithms"}
  ]
}
```

Best regards

Comment: Well, I know how to write the REST service from scratch. My issue is that I have ~40 tables to deal with and would like to exploit the auto-generation.

Comment: Fair enough, apologies. But your question doesn't reflect that at all. Its written like a "gimme the codez". There is no show of personal effort other than the fact that you mention you clicked some buttons. If you expect a collection to be serialized into the REST output, then surely you know that posting the actual code involved is a good idea?

Comment: Its amazing how many times I have to read people just actively refusing to provide basic available information, a small effort to make, because they "think it doesn't help" - being the people asking for help and not knowing what to do. Good luck with it.

Comment: I don't think that posting the auto-generated entity and auto-generated REST service would help at all, sincerely. 
It's not a matter of how to serialize a collection. The service is working properly: I do not expect it to add collections to related entities. 
Rather, I want to know how to edit such a service. Adding a collection of related entities is just an example.
Only someone who has experience with this Netbeans functionality can help me.

Comment: I am convinced that you need to have experience with this, because otherwise you don't know where to put your hands, just like me. As I said, I don't know where to edit. Should I post the whole project? 
Still, you are free to try by yourself. Here are the steps.
1 - genereate a DB with 2 entities and a 1-N relationship
2 - create a web project in Netbeans
3 - right click on the project and then New > Other > Web Services > RESTful Web Services from Database.
4 - good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like I got it working, but I don't know if this is the most elegant way to do it.

Here's what I did.

1) go to the auto-generated *child* entity class (i.e. `Exam.java`) and add a custom NamedQuery to the NamedQueries annotation. For instance,

```
@NamedQueries({
... default auto-generated stuff ...
@NamedQuery(name = "getExamsOfStudent", query="SELECT e FROM Exams e WHERE e.student.ID =: studentID")})
```

2) go to the auto-generated *child* REST service class (i.e. `ExamFacadeREST.java` and add a method to retrieve the children of a parent, using the NamedQuery defined in the entity class. For instance,

```
@GET
@Path("studentID/{studentID}")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
public List<Exam> getExamsOfStudent(@PathParam("studentID") Integer studentID) {  
  javax.persistence.Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Exam.getExamsOfStudent");
  query.setParameter("studentID", studentID);
  return query.getResultList();
}
```

At this point you have a REST service that retrieves the children of a parent entity.

However, this is not what I originally asked for. I would like to retrieve the exams as a collection, inside the student JSON, when performing the GET (by id) of the student. 
In order to do so simply go to the father entity REST service, (i.e. `StudentFacadeREST.java`) and properly edit the `find` method.

Does anyone know a more elegant way to do it?

**EDIT 1:** I'm trying the second method (to retrieve the exams as a collection, inside the student JSON, when performing the GET of the student) and I see that the collection does not get serialized into the output JSON. Any advice on this?

**EDIT 2:** I got it. For "generally extending" a service the first part of my answer above is good. However, if you want to obtain the serialization of collections that are already mapped as relations in the DB, simply properly remove the relative `@XmlTransient` annotations in the entity auto-generated classes. Take care to avoid circular references, that is you will probably need to **add** an `@XmlTransient` annotation to the *"getParent()"* method in the child entity class. 
For this example:
(A) go to the `Student` entity class and remove the `@XmlTransient` annotation from the `getExamsCollection()` method;
(B) go to the `Exam` entity class and **add** the `@XmlTransient` annotation to the `getStudent()` method.

Hope this helps.

Best regards